# How to call the methods of 3 other classes into another class in python

Tags: python, oop

So for now i have build 3 classes

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcol


color_dict = mcol.TABLEAU_COLORS


def lin2db(x):
    return 10*np.log10(x)


def db2lin(x):
    return 10**(x/10)

class ADC():
    fs_step = 2.75625e3
    def __init__(self,n_bit):
        self.n_bit=n_bit

    @property
    def snr(self):
        n_bit=self.n_bit
        M=2**n_bit
        snr_lin=M**2
        return snr_lin

    @property
    def snr_db(self):
        snr_lin=self.snr
        snr_db=lin2db(snr_lin)
        return snr_db

    @property
    def m(self):
        M=2**self.n_bit
        return M


class Digital_signal_information(object):
    def __init__(self, signal_power :float, noise_power :float, n_bit_mod:int):
        self.__signal_power=signal_power
        self.__noise_power=noise_power
        self.__n_bit_mod=n_bit_mod

    @property
    def nbit_mod(self):
        return self.__n_bit_mod

    @nbit_mod.setter
    def set_nbit_mod(self,value):
        self.__n_bit_mod=value

    @property
    def signal_power(self):
        return self.__signal_power

    @property
    def noise_power(self):
        return self.__noise_power

    @noise_power.setter
    def set_noise_power(self):
        self.__noise_power=0;


class Line(object):
    def __init__(self, loss_coefficient: float, length: float):
        self._loss_coefficient = loss_coefficient/1000
        self._length = length/1000

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self._length

    @property
    def loss_coefficient(self):
        return self._loss_coefficient;

    @property
    def Loss(self):
        return self.loss_coefficient * self.length

    def Noise_Generation(self,sn):
        return 1e-9 * sn * self.length

    def  snr_digital(self,sn):
        return  lin2db(sn)-lin2db(self.Noise_Generation(sn))-self.Loss
```

I know that they work individually without any problems if you define the stuff outside(i will later in another function) example

```
dsi=Digital_signal_information(1,2,3)
sn=dsi.signal_power
l=Line(1,2)
print(l.snr_digital(sn))
```

So it will print what i want.

Thing is that at the 4th `Class PCM` the project says:

Modify the class `PCM`considering as input attributes: `Digital_signal_information`,`ADC`,`Line` such that `PCM` acts as a container class which defines the transmission system in use. Modify the method `snr`, which has to retrieve the `snr_digital`from `Line` and with this we need to print out the `db2lin` version of it(its just a function defined in the beginning)

Thing is how do i do this? Considering that there are many other functions to be defined as well? How do i call correctly these functions from the other Classes.

The idea is not to initialize most of them because we will do so in an `exercise` function after we are done.

How would you continue beyond this

```
class PCM(ADC,Digital_signal_information,Line):


    def snr(self):
        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you want to create a container class `PCM` that takes instances of `Digital_signal_information`, `ADC`, and `Line` as input attributes. To do this, you can modify the `__init__` method of the `PCM` class and create properties to access these instances. Then you can define the `snr` method to call the `snr_digital` method from the `Line` class and convert it to linear using the `db2lin` function. Here's a possible implementation:

```py
class PCM:
    def __init__(self, digital_signal_info: Digital_signal_information, adc: ADC, line: Line):
        self._digital_signal_info = digital_signal_info
        self._adc = adc
        self._line = line

    @property
    def digital_signal_info(self):
        return self._digital_signal_info

    @property
    def adc(self):
        return self._adc

    @property
    def line(self):
        return self._line

    def snr(self):
        sn = self.digital_signal_info.signal_power
        snr_digital_db = self.line.snr_digital(sn)
        snr_digital_lin = db2lin(snr_digital_db)
        return snr_digital_lin
```

Now you can create instances of `Digital_signal_information`, `ADC`, and `Line`, and then create an instance of the `PCM` class using those instances. For example:

```py
dsi = Digital_signal_information(1, 2, 3)
adc = ADC(10)
line = Line(1, 2)
pcm = PCM(dsi, adc, line)

print(pcm.snr())
```

This should print the SNR value in linear scale as you wanted.

Hope you got your answer :)